# org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The end tag "&lt;/form:form" is unbalanced

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-mvc, jsp, exception

I've problem this problem in Spring Java Application

When I want to enter the localhost:8080/editEvent page I get the error code 500 and on eclipse I get this error
This is the error:

```
2020-06-29 11:11:50.128 ERROR 1114 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [/editEvent.jsp (line: [117], column: [1]) The end tag "&lt;/form:form" is unbalanced] with root cause org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /editEvent.jsp (line: [117], column: [1]) The end tag "&lt;/form:form" is unbalanced
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:42) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:292) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:98) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.checkUnbalancedEndTag(Parser.java:1606) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1471) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseBody(Parser.java:1683) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseOptionalBody(Parser.java:1016) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseCustomTag(Parser.java:1291) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1470) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseBody(Parser.java:1683) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseOptionalBody(Parser.java:1016) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseCustomTag(Parser.java:1291) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1470) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:144) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:244) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parse(ParserController.java:105) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:386) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:362) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:346) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:605) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:400) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:712) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:459) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:384) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:312) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter$HeaderWriterRequestDispatcher.forward(HeaderWriterFilter.java:172) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:171) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:316) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1373) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1118) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1057) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:118) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:158) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:117) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:526) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:860) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1591) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830) ~[na:na]
```

editEvent.jsp

```html
<%@include file="common/header.jspf"%>
<div class="container">
    <form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="event">
        <hr>
        <h1 class="form-heading">Modifica evento</h1>
        <hr>
        <div class="row">
            <spring:bind path="title">
                <div class="form-group ${status.error ? 'has-error' : ''} col-sm-6">
                    <h5>Titolo</h5>
                    <form:input type="text" path="title" class="form-control"
                        autofocus="true" value="${event.title}"></form:input>
                    <form:errors path="title"></form:errors>
                </div>
            </spring:bind>
            <spring:bind path="description">
                <div class="form-group ${status.error ? 'has-error' : ''} col-sm-6">
                    <h5>Descrizione</h5>
                    <form:textarea type="text" path="description" class="form-control"
                        value="${event.description}"></form:textarea>
                    <form:errors path="description"></form:errors>
                </div>
            </spring:bind>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="row">
            <spring:bind path="category">
                <div class="form-group ${status.error ? 'has-error' : ''} col-sm-4">
                    <h5>Categoria</h5>
                    <form:select type="text" path="category" class="form-control"
                        value="${event.category}">
                        <form:option value="Sport"></form:option>
                        <form:option value="Studio"></form:option>
                        <form:option value="Giochi"></form:option>
                        <form:option value="Altro"></form:option>
                    </form:select>
                    <form:errors path="category"></form:errors>
                </div>
            </spring:bind>
            <spring:bind path="max_member">
                <div class="form-group ${status.error ? 'has-error' : ''} col-sm-4">
                    <h5>Numero dei partecipanti</h5>
                    <form:input type="number" path="max_member" class="form-control"
                        value="${event.max_member}"></form:input>
                    <form:errors path="max_member"></form:errors>
                </div>
            </spring:bind>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="row">
            <spring:bind path="city">
                <div class="form-group ${status.error ? 'has-error' : ''} col-sm-4">
                    <h5>Città</h5>
                    <form:input type="text" path="city" class="form-control"
                        value="${event.city}"></form:input>
                    <form:errors path="city"></form:errors>
                </div>
            </spring:bind>
            <spring:bind path="place">
                <div class="form-group ${status.error ? 'has-error' : ''} col-sm-4">
                    <h5>Luogo</h5>
                    <form:input type="text" path="place" class="form-control"
                        value="${event.place}"></form:input>
                    <form:errors path="place"></form:errors>
                </div>
            </spring:bind>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="row">
            <spring:bind path="date">
                <div class="form-group ${status.error ? 'has-error' : ''} col-sm-4">
                    <h5>Data</h5>
                    <form:input type="date" path="date" class="form-control"
                        value="${event.date}"></form:input>
                    <form:errors path="date"></form:errors>
                </div>
            </spring:bind>
            <spring:bind path="time">
                <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
                    <h5>Orario</h5>
                    <form:input type="time" path="time" class="form-control"
                        value="${event.time}"></form:input>
                </div>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="row">
            <spring:bind path="cost">
                <div class="form-group ${status.error ? 'has-error' : ''} col-sm-3">
                    <h5>Costo</h5>
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <div class="input-group-text">&euro;</div>
                        <form:input type="number" path="cost" class="form-control"
                            value="${event.cost}"></form:input>
                    </div>
                    <form:errors path="cost"></form:errors>
                </div>
            </spring:bind>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <spring:bind path="username">
                <div class="form-group col-sm-3 invisible">
                    <form:select type="text" path="username" class="form-control">
                        <form:option value="${event.username}"></form:option>
                    </form:select>
                </div>
            </spring:bind>
        </div>
        <div class="row text-center col-sm-12">
            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit">
                <i class="fas fa-save"></i> Salva
            </button>
            <hr>
            <a class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" role="button" href="myEvents"> <i
                class="fas fa-window-close"></i> Annulla
            </a>
        </div>
    </form:form>
</div>
<%@include file="common/footer.jspf"%>
```

Why i have this error? The code seems to me balance. The problem appears only on this page. The rest of the code works

Answer (score 0):

```
<spring:bind path="time">
```

seems to be missing a closing

```
</spring:bind>
```

Please try if this solves the error.

The Jasper error messages can be somewhat misleading as a missing closing tag can unbalance everything that comes afterwards.

Comment: yes I solved it! I hadn't closed </spring:bind> after "time". Thank you